# Node js asynchronous calls

Tags: node.js

Does this code defy the nature of nodejs asynchronous calls?

```
app.post('/p', function (req, res) {
  question.find(1, function (err, count) {
    qu = count[0].question;

    res.render('lobby', {
      q: qu
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Any particular reason to make you assume it does?

Comment: nope, that looks good.

Comment: I was having the problem of moving the render outside the question.find function and I needed to do it by using callbacks

Comment: Correct. If the call to res.render() was outside question.find() then it will execute before the find returns. By calling res.render() inside the callback you guarantee that is called at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing about the code you posted "defies the nature of nodejs asynchronous calls".